# Elasticsearch throwing the exception: NoNodeAvailableException occured : No node available

Tags: playframework, elasticsearch

I'm decided to try my first use for elasticsearch on a simple to-do list application. I followed [this video](http://geeks.aretotally.in/play-elastic-search-module-new-0-0-5-release-with-screencast) to use the module and modified nothing in the module itself all what i did was creating the application and adding the class search.java in the controllers.

```
Execution exception
NoNodeAvailableException occured : No node available

In {module:elasticsearch-0.4}/app/controllers/elasticsearch/ElasticSearchController.java (around line 367)

363:
            // FIXME Currently we ignore the orderBy and order fields
364:
            query.from((page - 1) * getPageSize()).size(getPageSize());
365:
            query.hydrate(true);
366:

367:
            return query.fetch();
368:
        }
```

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem, what I did was:

1.Check if the nodes have the correct port open with:

```
telnet [ip address] 9300
Trying [ip address]
Connected to mynode1 ([ip address]).
Escape character is '^]'.
telnet> quit
Connection closed.
```

2.Check that everything is ok with telnet =):

```
$ telnet [ip address] 9400
Trying [ip address]...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

3.Make sure you have the correct version of elasticsearch!

In the [elasticsearch plugin](https://github.com/nboire/play2-elasticsearch) that I'm using elastisearch 0.19.10 is used. When I installed elasticsearch on my server I accidentally used 0.20.1 which caused the:
**NoNodeAvailableException occured : No node available** exception.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

1. Have you configured your elasticsearch nodes in your `application.conf`? More specifically 
   `elasticsearch.client=mynode1:9200,mynode2:9200`
2. You can also check if your elasticsearch nodes are running fine by using the [elasticsearch-head plugin](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/modules/plugins.html).