# Elasticsearch - No node available

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm getting this error for a few hours.. I'm using Play 2.2.0 and Elasticsearch 0.90.7!

Can anyone help me?

```
play.api.Application$$anon$1: Execution exception[[NoNodeAvailableException: No node available]]
        at play.api.Application$class.handleError(Application.scala:293) ~[play_2.10-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
        at play.api.DefaultApplication.handleError(Application.scala:399) ~[play_2.10-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
        at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$applyOrElse$3.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:261) ~[play_2.10-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
        at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$applyOrElse$3.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:261) ~[play_2.10-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
        at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
        at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$2.applyOrElse(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:261) ~[play_2.10-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
org.elasticsearch.client.transport.NoNodeAvailableException: No node available
        at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService$RetryListener.onFailure(TransportClientNodesService.java:256) ~[elasticsearch-0.90.7.jar:na]
        at org.elasticsearch.action.TransportActionNodeProxy$1.handleException(TransportActionNodeProxy.java:89) ~[elasticsearch-0.90.7.jar:na]
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService$Adapter$2$1.run(TransportService.java:316) ~[elasticsearch-0.90.7.jar:na]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
```

Comment: What are you doing that is resulting in this error message

Comment: This error appears when I try to upload a few documents - but it's random. Sometimes everything is ok, and sometimes and got the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually the error you are getting means that your client cannot connect to the elasticsearch node(s).

- Check that you are passing the correct parameters to your client
- Check that you do not have issues with a firewall
- Provide a bit more info on your situation as Nick said above, e.g. do you deploy your elastic search on a node on a cloud infrastructure like azure? In this case for example your client might time out because it cannot ping the nodes.

and you can also check some other similar cases in here, e.g. [No Node Available Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10218156/elasticsearch-throwing-the-exception-nonodeavailableexception-occured-no-node?rq=1)

Comment: the parameters are just fine, because sometimes works fine!the firewall it's fine as well. I'm not using cloud interface, it's localhost my application. I already search on google but nothing resolved my problem!

Comment: try to experiment with the client.transport.ping_timeout & client.transport.nodes_sampler_interval parameters of the transport client ( I assume you are using a transport client right?) and see observe how your app behaves.

Comment: I'm using the transport client.. I'll try, but what I have to put on each one?

Comment: default values are 5s for both of them, also check [link](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/client.html)

Answer (score 2):

In my case, client refused to connect to ES with this exception because cluster name on server was different then specified on client side. 
Client connects to ES, looks for desired cluster name, and then fails saying no node available. But in reality, that should mean that no node belongs to cluster with name specified on client side.

That can by fixed either by specifying a correct cluster name, or by setting `client.transport.ignore_cluster_name` to true.

Answer (score 1):

Are you closing off your connections? It could be you're firing stuff off to ElasticSearch, but not closing down your connections. Eventually ES will have "No nodes available"

```
try{
  Client client //set it up
  client.prepareSearch //do something
}

finally {
  client.close(); //close it down
}
```

Comment: so if you have a lot of indexing happening per second, closing each connection for each index only increase the overhead if not create even more problem?

Comment: It all depends how your application is architected. But, sounds like the bulk API is for you? http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to try these settings of ES

```
client.transport.sniff=true
sniffOnConnectionFault=true
```