# Can't create InetSocketTransportAddress in TransportClient: NoNodeAvailableException[None of the configured nodes -are available: []]

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-2.0

*UPDATED: Hopefully clearer details and code...*

I'm trying to make my first Java application to talk to ElasticSearch, which is running on this node (timestamps and log-levels removed):

```
$ bin/elasticsearch
[bootstrap          ]Unable to lock JVM Memory: error=78,reason=Function not implemented
[bootstrap          ]This can result in part of the JVM being swapped out.
[node               ][clustername-node.01] version[2.0.0], pid[49252], build[de54438/2015-10-22T08:09:48Z]
[node               ][clustername-node.01] initializing ...
[plugins            ][clustername-node.01] loaded [license, marvel], sites []
[env                ][clustername-node.01] using [1] data paths, mounts [[/ (/dev/disk1)]], net usable_space [164.4gb], net total_space [232.5gb], spins? [unknown], types [hfs]
[node               ][clustername-node.01] initialized
[node               ][clustername-node.01] starting ...
[transport          ][clustername-node.01] publish_address {127.0.0.1:9300}, bound_addresses {127.0.0.1:9300}
[discovery          ][clustername-node.01] clustername/AM4lm0ZBS_6FofhC0UbNIA
[cluster.service    ][clustername-node.01] new_master {clustername-node.01}{AM4lm0ZBS_6FofhC0UbNIA}{127.0.0.1}{127.0.0.1:9300}, reason: zen-disco-join(elected_as_master, [0] joins received)
[http               ][clustername-node.01] publish_address {127.0.0.1:9200}, bound_addresses {127.0.0.1:9200}
[node               ][clustername-node.01] started
[license.plugin.core][clustername-node.01] license [3ff50767-f1a5-4bac-8e35-c7a131384fd9] - valid
[license.plugin.core][clustername-node.01]
[gateway            ][clustername-node.01] recovered [14] indices into cluster_state
```

With DEBUG-ing, as suggested by @Val, these additional lines are also included in the above output:

```
[transport.netty][clustername.01] using profile[default], worker_count[8], port[9300-9400], bind_host[null], publish_host[null], compress[false], connect_timeout[30s], connections_per_node[2/3/6/1/1], receive_predictor[512kb->512kb]
[transport.netty][clustername.01] binding server bootstrap to: 127.0.0.1
[transport.netty][clustername.01] Bound profile [default] to address {127.0.0.1:9300}
```

The address portion:

```
publish_address {127.0.0.1:9300}, bound_addresses {127.0.0.1:9300}
clustername/AM4lm0ZBS_6FofhC0UbNIA
new_master {clustername-node.01}{AM4lm0ZBS_6FofhC0UbNIA}{127.0.0.1}{127.0.0.1:9300}, reason: zen-disco-join(elected_as_master, [0] joins received)
publish_address {127.0.0.1:9200}, bound_addresses {127.0.0.1:9200}
```

I've [confirmed the IP and port](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14066524/2736496) is running:

```
$ bin/elasticsearch --version
Version: 2.0.0, Build: de54438/2015-10-22T08:09:48Z, JVM: 1.8.0_45
$ telnet 127.0.0.1 9300
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.

^CConnection closed by foreign host.
$ telnet 127.0.0.1 9301
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: connect to address 127.0.0.1: Connection refused
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host
$
```

9300 is there, 9301 isn't, as expected. I'm [reasonably sure](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-transport.html) that port 9300 is correct for a Java TransportClient.

But no matter how I try to create the `InetSocketTransportAddress`...

```
import org.elasticsearch.action.get.GetResponse;
import org.elasticsearch.client.Client;
import org.elasticsearch.client.transport.NoNodeAvailableException;
import org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient;
import org.elasticsearch.common.settings.Settings;
import org.elasticsearch.common.transport.InetSocketTransportAddress;

import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

public class TrivialClient {

   public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException {
      InetSocketTransportAddress transportAddress = new InetSocketTransportAddress(
            InetAddress.getLocalHost(), 9300);
      createClientPrintResponse("getLocalHost", transportAddress);

      transportAddress = new InetSocketTransportAddress(
                  InetAddress.getByName("localhost"), 9300);

      createClientPrintResponse("getByName(\"localhost\")", transportAddress);

//Does not compile in ElasticSearch 2.0
//      transportAddress = new InetSocketTransportAddress("localhost", 9300);
//      createClientPrintResponse("getByName(\"localhost\")", transportAddress);

      transportAddress = new InetSocketTransportAddress(
            InetAddress.getByAddress(new byte[]{127, 0, 0, 1}), 9300);
      createClientPrintResponse("getByAddress(new byte[] {127, 0, 0, 1})", transportAddress);

      transportAddress =
            new InetSocketTransportAddress(new InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1", 9300));
      createClientPrintResponse("InetSocketAddress", transportAddress);
   }

   private static void createClientPrintResponse(String description,
                                      InetSocketTransportAddress transportAddress) {
      Settings settings = Settings.settingsBuilder()
            .put("cluster.name", "clustername").build();
      Client client;
      client = TransportClient.builder().settings(settings).build().
            addTransportAddress(transportAddress);
      try {
         GetResponse response = client.prepareGet("comicbook", "superhero", "1").get();
         System.out.println(description + ": " + response);
      } catch (NoNodeAvailableException e) {
         System.out.println(description + ": " + e);
         //e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
}
```

...it fails with:

```
getLocalHost: NoNodeAvailableException[None of the configured nodes are available: []]
getByName("localhost"): NoNodeAvailableException[None of the configured nodes are available: []]
getByAddress(new byte[] {127, 0, 0, 1}): NoNodeAvailableException[None of the configured nodes are available: []]
InetSocketAddress: NoNodeAvailableException[None of the configured nodes are available: []]
```

The stack trace:

```
NoNodeAvailableException[None of the configured nodes are available: []]
getLocalHost: NoNodeAvailableException[None of the configured nodes are available: []]
   at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService.ensureNodesAreAvailable(TransportClientNodesService.java:280)
   at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService.execute(TransportClientNodesService.java:197)
   at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.support.TransportProxyClient.execute(TransportProxyClient.java:55)
   at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient.doExecute(TransportClient.java:272)
   at org.elasticsearch.client.support.AbstractClient.execute(AbstractClient.java:347)
   at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionRequestBuilder.execute(ActionRequestBuilder.java:85)
   at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionRequestBuilder.execute(ActionRequestBuilder.java:59)
   at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionRequestBuilder.get(ActionRequestBuilder.java:67)
   at springes.esonly.TrivialClient.createClientPrintResponse(TrivialClient.java:47)
   at springes.esonly.TrivialClient.main(TrivialClient.java:19)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
   at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Possible this is already answered , [Check The answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33522581/elasticsearch-2-0-transport-client-no-node-available-exception/33568326#33568326)

Comment: I don't understand that answer. My settings: `network.host: 127.0.0.1`, which is the ip listed in the elasticsearch log when I start the node, and is what I'm using in the Java code. I don't see any other `host` related configuration settings in elasticsearch.yml.

Comment: In your `config/logging.yml` file, can you add the `transport: DEBUG` in the logger section and then update your startup logs with what you see?

Comment: @Val: Appreciate the suggestion. Added. Nothing obvious in it as far as I can tell...

Answer (score 3):

You'll have to specify the name of the cluster:

```
Settings settings = Settings.settingsBuilder()
  .put("cluster.name", "my_cluster_name").build();

Client client = TransportClient.builder().settings(settings).build()
  .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(new InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1", 9300)));
```

Refer: 
https://discuss.elastic.co/t/elasticsearch-in-java-transportclient-nonodeavailableexception-none-of-the-configured-nodesare-available/34452